# Probability of not getting any left handed people in study

Tags: statistics

The question says about 11% of the world population is left handed. If you pick a random sample of ten people, what is the probability of getting no left handed people?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please describe what you have tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: If $p$ is the proportion of left handed people, then the probability of getting no left handed people is $(1-p)^{10}$

Comment: The probability a person is a rightie is about $0.89$. The probability $10$ people in a row are righties is $\dots$.

Answer (score 0):

If $L$ is the event that the selected person is left-handed, then
$$P(L^C)=(1-P(L))^{10} = (1-0.11)^{10} \simeq 0.31$$
So, the answer of your question is $31%$.